# Cannot access nextjs app using local network ip address

Tags: javascript, reactjs, networking, next.js

I have a NextJs app and I am trying to access the website on my phone which is connected to the same Wifi so I can do some live changes but for some reason its not working. I have spent few hours but I cannot find a way to debug this or know whats causing the issue.

If I go to **localhost:3000** on my chrome browser on my mac then its all fine. It loads the website.

If I go to **localhost:3000** on my iPhone Simulator on my mac then it fails because its sending **https://localhost:3000** to get the **_next** assets.

The exact same happens when I try to use my local ip address instead of localhost.

I have tried the **next dev -H ip-address** but still the same error.

I want to know why are all my requests to my ip being redirect to https or why is the iphone simulator requests to localhost is being proxied to https.

[image]

Comment: you need to host the website from your computer, essentially your computer is a server. You can search around this topic over internet.

Comment: @windmaomao that makes no sense though. Everything else works, I have multiple nodejs apis, react apps, react native apps that works fine. I dont understand why next is throwing these errors